# Which are places in Germany that a traveler should visit?

Tags: germany, recommendations, tourist-traps

What are places in Germany -Hanover and some cities around it- that you recommend people to visit? Like [this art museum in Essen](http://www.saatchi-gallery.co.uk/museums/museum-profile/Museum+Folkwang,+Essen/396.html).

**EDIT**:  I don't have enough time, so I want to make sure it's worth it to visit before getting there. Better if it's where you've visited yourself.

Comment: It really depends on what you're interested in. Just art museums?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I believe there are places most people are interested in, don't you agree? I haven't heard of any popular ones in Germany, something like Eiffel tower in France.

Comment: You never heard e.g. of the Brandenburg Gate or the Cathedral of Cologne or Checkpoint Charley?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Not really, I don't know much about Germany and its culture, plus I'll only stay 5 days there.

Comment: @Gigili - sorry to have to close, but from the FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. " - and we try not to have "things that are overly broad or related to an overly big geographical region ".  If you have a specific set of criteria, we'll be happy to answer - like 'What arts museums are recommended in Germany', or 'what remains of the Berlin Wall are accessible to the public' - but as it stands, this question is too broad and solicits opinion, rather than direct answers.

Comment: @Gigili: Which parts of Germany? North or South? Rural or urban? Traditional or Modern? "Crowded" or left alone? You need to narrow down your question in these and other ways to make in answerable.

Comment: @Mark Mayo: I've edited my question.

Comment: @Mark Mayo: I don't understand what's wrong with my question, you could make it CW instead of simply voting to close, it'll help many users. anyway, I cannot detele it and nice people are downvoting it without even knowing what is the question.

Comment: [Use of community wiki is discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) and even if it is used, the question itself must be considered on-topic and answerable for the site. As it stands, the question is very broad due the the various criteria mentioned by others above. However, please do not take this personally and do feel free to edit your question to narrow down it's scope. People will be able to re-vote if the question is re-opened so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you're interested in. I suppose that you're looking for art museums like you mentioned in your example.

Therefore I really can recommend this list of art museums in Germany:

http://www.artcyclopedia.com/museums/art-museums-in-germany.html

I don't know all of them, but I visited and can recommend:

- Akademie der Künste in Berlin
- Mies van der Rohr Haus in Berlin
- Alte Pinakothek in Munich
- Architekturmuseum der Technischen Universität in Munich
- Museum for Applied Arts in Cologne

If you really want to just visit the 2 or 3 most important sights in whole Germany, I would recommend first spend some days in Berlin, the either go to the area around Cologne and then to Munich or over Dresden to Munich.

In Berlin, there are really a lot of interesting sights, especially a lot of museums (e.g. the Museumsinsel, a island that is full of museums) and naturally a lot of places that remember the division of Germany (e.g. Checkpoint Charley) or the [Holocaust](http://www.holocaust-denkmal-berlin.de/). In my opinion also the TV tower is really worth a visit. You can also check out the Brandenbourg Gate, the Column of Victory (Siegessäule) or the Bundestag.

In Munich there is also a lot to do. You have the choice between some cultural activities like museums, or you can spend your time in the various beer gardens, especially the Hofbräuhaus are known worldwide. At the moment there is also the [Oktoberfest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oktoberfest) that attracts many visitors. I personally would also visit the old [Olympic Stadium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Stadium_%28Munich%29) with its famous roof designed by Günther Behnisch. There you can also climb a tower that will provides you with a great look over the city.

Comment: Thanks, I've found some of them in Google.But the problem is I don't have enough time and I just can visit a few places. So I asked the question to make sure that for example, this place is worth the time you spend.

Comment: @Gigili I updated my answer